# Sobolev "unit ball" compact in $L^p$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

We consider $I=(0,1)$, and $1< p \leq \infty$. If $B = \{ f \in W^{1,p}(0,1); ||f||_p + ||f'||_p \leq 1 \}$, how to show that $B$ is compact in $L^p(0,1)$?

Comment: This is a famous theorem, generally attributed to Rellich. It is proven in Evans PDE and I am sure there are numerous other proofs online.

Comment: (More precisely, it is a corollary of Rellich's theorem.)

Comment: @Ian The one-dimensional case is easier: Hölder's inequality gives equicontinuity, so compactness holds even in the uniform norm, by Arzeà-Ascoli.

Comment: @Ian Could u please tell me in which section of Evans can i find what u say, sorry for an old post.